# zsh: command not found: svn_prompt_info

Tags: zsh

I install the oh-my-zsh through the gist
https://gist.github.com/tsabat/1498393

However, whatever command I typed in the shell, the execute the command then print "zsh: command not found: svn_prompt_info". For example:

```
➜  ~ ls
test.py
zsh: command not found: svn_prompt_info
```

My zsh config is as follows. I don't enable the svn plugin

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="random"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment this to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment to change how often before auto-updates occur? (in days)
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable command autocorrection
# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable marking untracked files under
# VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories much,
# much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable svi plugin .

```
plugins=(git svn)
```

Modify the plugin line as follows.save and close. Then restart zsh again.

Comment: problem solved. but I don't use svn indeed.

Comment: It's just a plug in. Not everything